# Surviving user timezones in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone, ruby-on-rails-7

I'm trying to play nice with TimeZones in Rails.

I have a model called `Event` which has the datetime field `starts_at` and string field `timezone`. I'm however just a bit confused as to the best practice for managing these dates as I am working with the date of these Events which are quite different from the application's timezone.

By default rails is using the timezone of my application which is CEST and so by default when I save a date for an Event it uses this timezone. However 99% of the time we think of the date in terms of the client for whom we set the timezone on the model. So the default of setting it in our timezone is not great.

Should I:

1. Keep setting these dates relative to my time, eg `starts_at` set in CEST and
   interpret them into the client time, eg `client_starts_at`. However this is confusing since, we usually input `starts_at` relative to the client's time and not to our own.
2. Do some kind of getter/setter to be able to input dates as the users time. Which avoids most of the issue as all things go into UTC anyway.
3. Configure the model or controller to take into account the `timezone` field
   of the `Event` and thereby set every record `starts_at` into the
   correct timezone and then interpret the time zone for us into
   `local_starts_at`.
4. Perhaps i'd be better off separating `starts_at` into two fields separating `date` from `time`?

The option 3 or 4 seem better but does anyone know of a resource as this would seem to be a very common problem. Also I'm not sure if I should be managing these issues on the model level or dealing with it in the controller.

Thanks,

https://thoughtbot.com/blog/its-about-time-zones

Answer (score 1):

You can use `in_time_zone`.

```rb
def client_starts_at
  starts_at.in_time_zone(timezone)
end
```

No matter how it was stored, you'll get the right timezone.

You can even override the base method (not recommended):

```rb
def starts_at
  read_attribute(:starts_at).in_time_zone(timezone)
end
```